# What sentences say "for [infinitive]"?

Tags: infinitives, for-to-complementizers

I have the following phrase, or something like it:

- That's for to learn grammar.

I guess it's a common kind of construction, if confusing / malformed. Could I read it as missing an elided e.g. name?

- That's for Pat to learn grammar.

---

But I especially wondered if "to learn" could be read as an infinitive (I don't think it is in the 1st interpretation?). I'm curious because I think it can make sense to replace "to learn" with an adjective:

- That's for easy grammar.

And "to learn" I think can be an [infinitive](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitivephrase.htm) adjectival phrase:

- The best way to learn is lots of questions.

---

More generally, are there well formed sentences which say "... for [infinitive]..."?

Answer (score 1):

> [We don’t](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/infinitives-and-imperatives/infinitives-with-and-without-to) use the infinitive (with or without to) after prepositions:
>
> Lemon juice is useful for cleaning stained surfaces in the kitchen.
>
> Not: … is useful for clean … or … for to clean …

Though perhaps 'for' as [the conjunction meaning because](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#Conjunction) can appear before an infinitive

- For to sleep so long is foolish

Comment: correct me if that's not an infinitive in the last sentence

Answer (score 1):

This construction crops up in poetry or lyrics, but is not idiomatic, ie is not used in normal language.  eg  in this folk song:

> ### Springfield Mountain
>
> (Traditional / Roger McGuinn)
>
> On Springfield Mountain there did dwell
>   Right - tum - a - new - rife - a - lime - a - diddle - do
>   On Springfield Mountain there did dwell tum - a - row
>   On Springfield Mountain there did dwell a handsome youth I knew full well
>   Right - tum - a - new - rife - a - lime - a - diddle - do
>
> One Monday morning he did go
>   Right - tum - a - new - rife - a - lime - a - diddle - do
>   One Monday morning he did go tum - a - row
>   One Monday morning he did go Down in the meadow ***for to mow***
>   Right - tum - a - new - rife - a - lime - a - diddle - do

See the second-last line.  In this instance, "for" may be used simply to pad out the line to the required rhythm.

Comment: It is not idiomatic anymore, but it was very common in certain dialects previously. You still hear it sometimes in Hibernian English, and it is exceedingly common in Irish folk songs.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet by Hibernian do you mean "Scottish English (but not not gaelic)?"

Comment: No, Irish English (and not Gaelic, though an equivalent preposition meaning ‘for’, such as _chun_ or _fá choinne_, would be used in Gaelic in similar contexts, too). [Scottish English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_English) would be _Caledonian_, I suppose, though I’ve never seen anyone talk about ‘Caledonian English’, whereas [Hiberno-English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English) is quite common.

Comment: aha, I might have been thinking of the Edinburgh football team "Hibernian", which are sort of the Edinburgh equivalent of Glasgow Celtic, ie proudly displaying their Irish heritage.  Makes sense, thanks :)